# VueJS - Push an object to an array of objects inside an async function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vuejs2

I'm currently working on a Vue 2 project, and I have to push an object from outside the async function scoop.
Here's the code in subject below :

```
async getData() {
  return [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Slim",
    age: 5,
    location: 1500,
    breed: 500,
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Sol",
    age: 3,
    location: 1500,
    breed: 1,
  },
};
```

Is there a way to access and push the data of this array of objects from outside of the getData() scoop

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you declare an array outside the function scope and then add changes to it, or you can pass the update array as parameter.

```
let array = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Slim",
    age: 5,
    location: 1500,
    breed: 500,
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Sol",
    age: 3,
    location: 1500,
    breed: 1,
  }];

//pass array as a parameter
async getData(array){
    return array
}

//update your array
array.push("your object");

//pass updated array in function call
getData(array);
```

Comment: I have thought of this approach, but aren't there other ways to do it maybe without extracting the array from the getData() ?

Comment: why do you need to access the array, can you describe your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this approach,

```
async function getData(item) {
  return [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Slim",
    age: 5,
    location: 1500,
    breed: 500,
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Sol",
    age: 3,
    location: 1500,
    breed: 1,
  },
  item
  ]
};

getData(  {
    id: "3",
    name: "obj",
    age: 5,
    location: 1500,
    breed: 1,
  });
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I have been looking for this exact approach, it works!